# How do I get the COUNT of a field's value, as well as the "% of total" of that same value from the rest of the values in that field in one query?

Tags: sql, aggregation

Example to explain the question in the title:

table_name: fruits

| fruit_type |  <-- column header

|apple |

|apple |

|orange|

|orange|

So essentially, I want the simplest query to return the COUNT of the oranges in this column (which is 2), as well as a separate column of the % of oranges to overall types of fruit(which is 50%).

Specifically, I'm stuck at not only combining the two necessary requirements into one query, but also at how to get the second part (%) in general.

Answer (score 0):

You would use window functions:

```
select fruit_type, count(*), count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over ()
from fruit
group by fruit_type;
```

This returns the value for all fruit, not just oranges.

If you just want oranges, use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when fruit_type = 'orange' then 1.0 else 0 end)
from fruit;
```

Comment: Thank you, your second query helped me out! Question in regards to the first one though, what is the "over ()" part? And what is the significance of multiplying the count(*) by 1.0?

Comment: The `over ()` is for window/analytic functions, a very powerful part of the SQL language.  The `* 1.0` is because you did not specify your database, and some databases do integer division, so 1/2 = 0 rather than 0.5.